# How to scroll down to the item whose ID was included as query parameter in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

How can I scroll the page down to the item whose ID is included as a query param in the router?
I am using Vue router for routing.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1: Vue Router's scroll behavior

You could configure Vue Router's [scroll behavior](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) to automatically scroll to the element. This behavior applies to all views/pages, allowing the query for any route path.

```js
export default new VueRouter({
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition;
    }
    if (to.query && to.query.id) {
      return {
        selector: '#' + to.query.id,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/scrolling-to-element-by-id-from-query-param-4ltuc?file=/src/router.js)

#### Option 2: Watch `$route.query`

You could use [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) on a [template ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) along with a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on [`$route.query`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties) to call this scrolling function:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 ref="first">First</h1>
    <h1 ref="second">Second</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    scrollTo(name) {
      this.$refs[name]?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
    },
  },
  watch: {
    '$route.query'(query) {
      if (query.id) {
        this.scrollTo(query.id)
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/scrolling-to-element-by-id-from-query-param-forked-9nkvm?file=/src/views/Home.vue)

Comment: It's not working with dynamic refs. I am using the following structur for refs:

:ref="'item' + item.id" because refs are attached to loop items.

Comment: Can you link to a reproduction in Codesandbox?